# swift subclass init tangle

Tags: macos, swift, serialization, init

I have a base class with two init methods - one is designated with a list of parameters, the other is a convenience init that obtains the parameter values from an NSDictionary (which is used to serialise objects). All is well until I attempt to create a subclass - the convenience init produces an error if I attempt to call the matching super.init(...) and demands that I call a designated init of the subclass. The superclass contains the keys used to extract the parameter values and I don't want to duplicate the code or have public key values.

I could set up dummy values and use a separate loadFromDict() method (which can then be overridden) but this seems awkward. Is there another way?

Comment: A (minimal) code example would be helpful ...

Comment: You say you don't want "public" key values. Would "internal" key values work? If they are marked "internal", but part of the same module, then presumably the sub-class would be able to see them, and they still wouldn't be public. If they are "private", then that of course will not work...

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is normal, as if follows the rules for initialization in Swift. A convenience init must always call another init in the same class. The other init could be another convenience, or it could be a designated. At some point though a designated init needs to be called in the subclass before it calls up to the super class. Swift enforces that only a designated init can call up to super class init. This is from the [Swift Language reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203)

> To simplify the relationships between designated and convenience
>   initializers, Swift applies the following three rules for delegation
>   calls between initializers:
>
> **Rule 1**
>
> A designated initializer must call a designated initializer from its immediate superclass.
>
> **Rule 2**
>
> A convenience initializer must call another initializer from the same class.
>
> **Rule 3**
>
> A convenience initializer must ultimately call a designated initializer.
>
> A simple way to remember this is:
>
> Designated initializers must always delegate up.
>
> Convenience initializers must always delegate across.

Answer (score 0):

This portion of [the apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203) may also be helpful:

> Assuming that you provide default values for any new properties you introduce in a subclass, the following two rules apply:
>
> Rule 1
>
> If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers.
>
> Rule 2
>
> If your subclass provides an implementation of all of its superclass designated initializers—either by inheriting them as per rule 1, or by providing a custom implementation as part of its definition—then it automatically inherits all of the superclass convenience initializers.
>
> These rules apply even if your subclass adds further convenience initializers.
>
> NOTE
>
> A subclass can implement a superclass designated initializer as a subclass convenience initializer as part of satisfying rule 2.

This means that if your subclass overrides *all* of the superclasses designated initializers, then your subclass will inherit the convenience initializer that you want to avoid coding twice. In other words, you don't try to re-write the convenience initializer in the subclass at all. You just inherit it and use it as is.

Here is how it might look:

```
Superclass:              DesignatedInit   ConvenienceInit
                                |         /
                            (override)   /    // ConvenienceInit
                                |       /     // will call overridden
                                |      /      // designated initializer
Subclass:                DesignatedInit       // in subclass.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I've made the superclass convenience init into a designated one and duplicated the code from the other designated init, that seems to be the only way to call it from a subclass. Adding a 'setup' method that could be called later meant introducing optionals which confused the code.

To clarify my question, I wanted to subclass the convenience init so I could call super.init(...) as well as doing some subclass-specific stuff. This is now trivial with making it a designated init but it means that the two designated inits cannot share processing code, which is inconvenient.

I appreciate that the Swift init design is meant to protect coders from introducing bugs but it does feel a little too inflexible at times.

BTW I appreciate the helpful intention but posting chunks of documentation isn't ideal - just a link is fine.